# Insufficient permissions to the resource in https://pub.dartlang.org package repository

Tags: flutter

I got this error when I delete flutter-sdk and replace new flutter-sdk

```
Insufficient permissions to the resource in https://pub.dartlang.org package repository. You can modify credential using:
    pub token add https://pub.dartlang.org
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...                           
pub get failed (65;     pub token add https://pub.dartlang.org)
```

**flutter version** :

```
Flutter 2.8.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision cf44000065 (6 days ago) • 2021-12-08 14:06:50 -0800
Engine • revision 40a99c5951
Tools • Dart 2.15.0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First delete credentials:

```
rm ~/.pub-cache/credentials.json
```

After you try:

```
flutter upgrade
flutter pub cache repair
```

Comment: Not work :(
I got this error when I delete SDK and replace new SDK

Comment: I don't find any credentials.json file

Comment: You delete all pub-cache folder.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. You need to use a VPN.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the answer solved my issue and many others who live in Middle East. There is no need to edit or add any details. @Community

Answer (score 0):

I just restart my system and then try to do "flutter pub get" and it works :|,
And also I change my VPN.

Comment: You have delete first the folder pub-cache?

Comment: I also deleted pub-cache, but not sure what was the problem.

Comment: You have delete the cache and after with pub-get you recreate it, as I told you!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, make sure that follow these steps:

1. run `flutter clean`
2. make sure that you have reliable internet connection and if you are using VPN, make sure it has reliable connection
3. `run` your project again.